# how to get key and value from two hashes (if their key matches) in a third hash

Tags: ruby

Suppose i have two hashes say

```
hash1 = {1=>"a" , 2=>"b" ,3=>"c" , 4=>"d"}

hash2 = {2=>"whats" ,4 =>"up" ,5=> "dude"}
```

and i have to create a resultant hash such that if their keys matches then resultant hash must contain key (which is the the value in 1st hash) and value (which is the value corresponding matched key)

```
hash3 ={b=>"whats" ,d=>"up"}
```

Answer (score 7):

This construct may be a little cryptic but it also does the job.

```
hash1 = {1=>"a" , 2=>"b" ,3=>"c" , 4=>"d"}
hash2 = {2=>"whats" ,4 =>"up" ,5=> "dude"}

hash3 = Hash[(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).map do |k|
  [hash1[k], hash2[k]]
end]
hash3 # => {"b"=>"whats", "d"=>"up"}
```

Another way

```
hash3 = hash2.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), memo|
  memo[hash1[k]] = v if hash1[k]
end
hash3 # => {"b"=>"whats", "d"=>"up"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code.

```
hash1 = {1=>"a" , 2=>"b" ,3=>"c" , 4=>"d"}
hash2 = {2=>"whats" ,4 =>"up" ,5=> "dude"}
hash3 = {}
hash2.each_entry { |key, value| hash3[hash1[key]] = value if hash1.include? key }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h1 = {1=>"a" , 2=>"b" ,3=>"c" , 4=>"d"}
h2 = {2=>"whats" ,4 =>"up" ,5=> "dude"}
h3 = Hash[h1.update(h2){|k,o,n| [o,n]}.map{|k,v| v if v.is_a? Array}.compact]
# => {"b"=>"whats", "d"=>"up"}
h3 = Hash[h1.update(h2){|k,o,n| [o,n]}.select{|k,v| v.is_a? Array}.values]
# => {"b"=>"whats", "d"=>"up"}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
hash3 = {}
hash1.each_pair { |k, v| hash3[v] = hash2[k] }
```

Comment: it is not working , it is just giving hash1

Comment: no, it's setting hash3[value_in_hash1] = hash2[same_key] and it's doing this with each element in hash1

Comment: but I like falsetru's solution better, the conditional assignment was the right thing to do